# Measuring MySQL Replication Delay

Tags: mysql-replication, mysql5, ubuntu-11.04

How to measure MySQL replication delay between 2 MySQL servers ( 1 Master 1 Slave ) ?

Given that two Xeon E5620 grade 1U servers are separate machine in same network segment, using MySQL Community Server 5.1 running in Ubuntu Linux Server 11.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL command line, give command

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

and see the `Seconds_behind_ master` value.

Or if you want to script that somehow, the one-liner below returns how many seconds behind master the slave currently is.

```
mysql -u your_user -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G' | grep "Seconds_Behi" | awk '{ print $2; }'
```

Comment: Cool. May I ask what does the `\G` mean?

Comment: `\G` formats the status command output in more human-readable way and in this case makes the grep part easier, too. :) In other words, \G puts each status entry in its own line, without it you get a messy table-like output with ascii graphics and all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends how accurate you want to be and for what purpose.

I update a record on the master and then do several reads from the slave until I get the updated record. I'm working with a slow connection between the two seperate offices. So 0.1 second resolution is good enough for me.